# AWS Ubuntu 11.04 failing to apt-get update/upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apt

First, let it be known that it has been quite some time since I upgraded this particular server.

When I execute `sudo apt-get update` most of the endpoints seem to be reached fine. However there are a few rather disconcerting misses:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I try to move ahead with the `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get tons of errors looking like the following and nothing updates:

```
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.13-0ubuntu13.2
403  Forbidden
```

Is my servers sources list pointing to the wrong server or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [list of Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), Natty Narwhal hit end-of-life on Oct. 28, 2012 and is no longer supported.

[Here](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/09/17/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-reaches-end-of-life-on-october-28-2012/) is the announcement.

Comment: That will certainly do it. An upgrade to 12.04 is in order I suppose, I hope its not too much of a pain.